# Limiting number of selected rows in Vaadin Table

Tags: java, vaadin

In one of our applications we use the lazy query container to browse a potentially very large dataset. This works great. However, it is possible to select an arbitrary number of rows when using a multi-select table. 
In our case, this can lead to selecting up to 500.000 rows (Vaadin limit) and then crash the VM.

Is there a way to limit the number of selected rows?

Here is a sample that shows the problem:

```
public class UIImpl extends UI {
    private int SIZE = 500000;

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {

        // add a large table
        LazyQueryContainer lqc = new LazyQueryContainer(
            new QueryFactory() {
                public Query constructQuery(QueryDefinition qd) {
                    return new Query() {
                        @Override
                        public int size() {
                            return SIZE;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void saveItems(List<Item> addedItems, List<Item> modifiedItems, List<Item> removedItems) {   }

                        @Override
                        public List<Item> loadItems(int startIndex, int  count) {
                            List<Item> r = new ArrayList<>(count);
                            for (int i = startIndex; i<startIndex+count;i++) {
                                PropertysetItem item = new PropertysetItem();
                                item.addItemProperty("name", new ObjectProperty(i));
                                r.add(item);
                            }
                            return r;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean deleteAllItems() {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public Item constructItem() {
                            return null;
                        }
                    };
                }
            },
            null,
            20,
            false
        );

        lqc.addContainerProperty("name", Integer.class, null);

        Table table = new Table();
        table.setContainerDataSource(lqc);
        table.setMultiSelect(true);
        table.setSelectable(true);
        table.setImmediate(true);
        table.setVisibleColumns("name");
        table.setSizeFull();
        table.addValueChangeListener(new Property.ValueChangeListener() {
            public void valueChange(Property.ValueChangeEvent event) {
                System.err.println(event.getProperty().getValue());
            }
        });
        setContent(table);
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume that `selecting rows` you mean retrieving them from the DB and not selecting them by clicking in the UI table. If I'm correct and unless you have a very specific reason, it's worth considering not loading all 500k rows in memory. Instead load chunks of limited sizes, 20, 50, etc and display them in a _paged_ manner. When the user changes the page, you'd load only its corresponding rows.

Comment: This is really about avoiding the possibility that 500000 rows are selected on the UI. This is not about the database access. For example: With lazy query container, selecting the first row, scrolling down to the last row, holding SHIFT and selecting the last row will select ALL rows - possibly 500000, even though only a few have been loaded into memory. I want to avoid even handing out those 500000 rows (which, I think, requires a lot of local processing memory already).

Comment: Ok, nonetheless, do you have a requirement to display all of them?! There are a few situations where this would be considered a _normal_ requirement because such a huge number makes it difficult to follow and keep track of, usually resulting in a not-so-friendly UI

Comment: True. The approach here is however that you narrow things down by filtering until it gets manageable. Virtually (as per lazy loading) however you start from the whole dataset. That's simply how the application was designed.

Comment: Got it, good luck then. Perhaps you could consider a future improvement to shift the filtering in the DB query and paging the results. This should save you some OOM headaches

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to limit the number of rows a user is able to select you can use something similar to the following code:

```
public class TableWithSelectionLimit extends Table {

    private final int maxSelections= -1;
    private String[] lastSelected;

    public TableWithSelectionLimit(int maxSelections) {
      this.maxSelections = maxSelections;
    }

    @Override
    public void changeVariables(Object source, Map<String, Object> variables) {
      String[] selected = (String[]) variables.get("selected");
      if (selected != null && selected.length > maxSelections) {
        if (lastSelected != null) {
          variables.put("selected", lastSelected);
        } else {
          variables.remove("selected");
        }

        markAsDirty();
      } else {
        lastSelected = selected;
      }

      super.changeVariables(source, variables);
    }
}
```

This is of course optimizable, but it gives you an idea on how you could do it.

---

**Update**

For handling also selections produced using "Shift"+Click one has to handle/update these selection ranges additionally inside the method mentioned above.

Those can be retrieved using `variables.get("selectedRanges")` that will return a `String[]` containing items like `"8-10"` whereas the

- *first number* is: the start index of the selection range
- *second number* is: the amount of items selected starting at this index

Using this information it should be possible to update those values as wished and put them back into the variables using `variables.put("selectedRanges", updatedRanges)`.

**Attention:** do not forget to call `markAsDirty()` if the values are changed, as otherwise the changes won't be propagated to the client side.

Comment: But doesn't that mean that, say, 500000 rows have been selected and the ids have been sent to the server already? Sounds to me that at the point in time you test for selected.length>maxSelections, it's too late already.

Comment: This works if the selection is done by clicking (holding down ctrl). If you set the limit to 2, the user won't be able to click a third item in the table. How do you expect to do your selection?

Comment: Select the first row, scroll down to the last, hold SHIFT and select the last.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand. In that case you will have to handle the selected ranges too inside this method. You can get them by using `variables.get("selectedRanges")`. This will return a `String[]` containing items like `8-10` whereas the first number is the start index of the selection range and the second one the amount of items selected starting at this index.

Comment: Great. Just tried it and it does indeed work. Can you add that suggestion to your original suggestion so that I can mark it as answer?